# storing forms and their elements values in a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a single page web app.

For speed, I store each 'page' in the JS.

I have a problem which happens when there is a form on a page. If you fill in the form, and then store it in a js variable, and then retrieve it, the forms values have disappeared?

I use functions like:

```
var pages_html = {};

var $page = $('#some-page');
store_page($page);
$page.remove();

//some stuff on another page

var $retrieved_page = get_page('some-page');
console.log($retrieved_page.find('#some-input').val())
//consoles log is always blank / ''

function store_page(page){
    var page_id = $(page).attr('id');
    pages_html[page_id] = $(page);
}

function get_page(page_id){
    var page = pages_html[page_id];
    return $(page);
}
```

Everything else seems to work, i can store and retrieve pages as i wish, its just any values of form elements are lost. How can I work around this?

Comment: are you talking about when you submit it, if yes add an event listener for the submit and use event.preventDefault(); to prevent refreshing of page when form is submitted

Answer (score 0):

You cannot store it like that. Instead store it as serialized array. which you can then fill it back when needed. `serializeArray` returns Array of Objects which have `name` and `value`

```
var values = {};
function store_page(page){
    var page_id = $(page).attr('id');
    pages_html[page_id] = $(page);
    values[page_id] = $(page).find("form").serializeArray(); // serialize it
}
function get_page(page_id){
    var page = pages_html[page_id];
    values[page_id].forEach(function(obj){
        page.find('[name=' + obj.name + ']').val(obj.value) // add it again
    });
    return page; // and then return
}
```